# I want to insert data from one table into another at same time using stored procedure in SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

First Issue table

```
BookID | BookName | DateIssue | ReturnDate | PersonID
       |          |           |            |
1      | Sqlserver|  4/4/2015 |  5/5/2015  |  22
```

I want to insert the values from tblIssue into Return table but, couldn't...
    second Return table

```
BookID | BookName | DateIssue | ReturnDate | PersonID
       |          |           |            |
1      | Sqlserver|  4/4/2015 |  5/5/2015  |  22
```

query is running in sql server.. I thought, I have mistakes in sql server query

```
Stored proc query:



'CREATE PROCEDURE inserttwo
(
@BookID int,
@BookName nvarchar(50),
@DateIssue datetime,
@ReturnDate datetime,
@PersonID int
)

as

insert into tblReturn(BookID,BookName,DateIssue,ReturnDate,PersonID)
values(@BookID,@BookName,@DateIssue,@ReturnDate,@PersonID)

select * from  tblIssue
```

error in c#:

> Procedure or function 'inserttwo' expects parameter '@BookID',
>   which was not supplied.

here it is pointing error: sda.Fill(dt);

```
C# code: 


 public void storedproc()
        {
      string w = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LMS"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(w);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("inserttwo", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            conn.Open();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            metroGrid1.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to add the parameters

```
string w = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LMS"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(w))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("inserttwo", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = BookID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = BookName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateIssue", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ReturnDate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PersonID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PersonID;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        conn.Open();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        metroGrid1.DataSource = dt;
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

the procedure requires `@BookID,@BookName,@DateIssue,@ReturnDate,@PersonID` so you have to add them and fill them with values.

**UPDATE** To insert Data into 2 tables your procedure should look something like this without knowing your table structure it's impossible to give you a valid answer

```
'CREATE PROCEDURE inserttwo
(
@BookID int,
@BookName nvarchar(50),
@DateIssue datetime,
@ReturnDate datetime,
@PersonID int
)

as

insert into tblReturn(BookID,BookName,DateIssue,ReturnDate,PersonID)
values(@BookID,@BookName,@DateIssue,@ReturnDate,@PersonID)

insert into tblIssue(BookID,BookName,DateIssue,ReturnDate,PersonID)
values(@BookID,@BookName,@DateIssue,@ReturnDate,@PersonID)
```

Comment: it's giving an error after = to that BookId doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: @Warda yes, you have to set the value of the book you want to insert

Comment: no your procedure only inserts values into table `tblReturn`

Comment: I want to insert tbl issue values into table return??? but  I have doubt in the stored proc query...

Comment: For that you have to  use `select into tblReturn from tblIssue`. You can also add a where clause in case you have any conditions.

Comment: @GaganJaura u were right... I changed the code as u said me. It's inserting into return table but not in Issue tbl.. I want to insert the values into tbl Issue as well as tbl Return at once.. but current code is inserting into Return table only...

Comment: @fubo can u tell me how do I insert the data into tbl Issue n tbl Return at once...My code is inserting into return table but not in Issue tbl.. I want to insert the values into tbl Issue as well as tbl Return at once.. but current code is inserting into Return table only...

Answer (score 0):

Pass parameters command object.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx